# Is it possible to put double quotes in just a few columns using sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed, csv, columns

I'm doing my course completion work where I need to manipulate some columns of a .csv file that has six hundred thousand lines. I have already searched in several forums on sed and awk and I did not find anything like it (and unfortunately my knowledge about Linux is not very deep). What I found generally handles only one column or all ... what I need is to put double quotes only in the first, fifth, and sixth columns.

For example:

```
2018-03-18 4:56:17,255.255.255.255,00,ssh,admin,123
```

To be

```
"2018-03-18 4:56:17",255.255.255.255,00,ssh,"admin","123"
```

Still, maybe I still change some column since I'm just starting in data mining and I do not know what the configuration will be like in a few weeks, so if you can do a brief syntax of logic, I'll be eternally grateful.

Comment: What trouble did you have with extending a solution for one column?

Comment: `What I found generally handles only one column or all` please add those to question.. it will show your research effort..

Comment: Is the reason that you need to quote these column that they may contain commas?  This matters for most answers written so far.

Comment: To be more precise: If the reason that the fields needs to be quoted is that some of the data in those fields contain commas, then that would _invalidate_ every answer written so far.

Comment: I agree with Kusalananda. I have to ask: why are you trying to do this? This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`csvtool`](http://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/csv/) which has a helpful `format` command:

```
csvtool format '"%1",%2,%3,%4,"%5","%6"\n' file.csv
```

Example:

```
echo "2018-03-18 4:56:17,255.255.255.255,00,ssh,admin,123" |
csvtool format '"%1",%2,%3,%4,"%5","%6"\n' -
```

Output:

```
"2018-03-18 4:56:17",255.255.255.255,00,ssh,"admin","123"
```

---

`csvtool` also can `call` shell functions and external programs to parse lines from *.CSV* files.  To do the same thing using `printf`, but print the "*123*" in hexadecimal, do:

```
echo "2018-03-18 4:56:17,255.255.255.255,00,ssh,admin,123" | 
csvtool call "printf '\"%s\",%s,%s,%s,\"%s\",\"%x\"\n'" -
```

Output:

```
"2018-03-18 4:56:17",255.255.255.255,00,ssh,"admin","7b"
```

Answer (score 3):

I might approach it with awk this way:

1. set the output field separator to what the input field separator is, which we assign as the comma `-F,`
2. for each line, reassign the values of fields 1, 5, and 6 as being the original values but surrounded by double-quotes. The apparent quoting mess is because I used double-quotes to create the surrounding string, and because the only string I want to print *is* a double-quote, I have to escape it, so each double-quote that I want ends up being `"\""`.
3. Once the fields have been updated, print the newly-combined string.

The script is:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS } {$1="\""$1"\""; $5="\""$5"\""; $6="\""$6"\""; print }' < input.csv > output.csv
```

As you find that you need to quote more fields, simply do the same thing as with fields 1, 5, and 6 above.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`

```bsh
$ perl -F, -lane 'map {$_=qq("$_")} @F[0,4,5]; print join ",", @F' ip.txt
"2018-03-18 4:56:17",255.255.255.255,00,ssh,"admin","123"
```

- `-F,` use `,` as input field delimiter, results available in `@F` array
- `map {$_=qq("$_")} @F[0,4,5]` double quote required array elements. Index starts from `0`. The `qq` operator is used here to avoid escaping double quotes, `qq("$_")` is same as `"\"$_\""`
- `print join ",", @F` print the modified array with `,` as separator

Another way to do with `awk`

```bsh
$ awk -v q='"' 'BEGIN{split("1 5 6",a); FS=OFS=","}
                {for(i in a) $a[i]=q $a[i] q} 1' ip.txt
"2018-03-18 4:56:17",255.255.255.255,00,ssh,"admin","123"
```

- `-v q='"'` save double quote as value in `q` variable
- `split("1 5 6",a)` save index to be changed as values in `a` array (default split on whitespace, FS is not yet changed)
- `FS=OFS=","` change input/output delimiter to `,`
- `for(i in a) $a[i]=q $a[i] q` change required fields
- `1` idiomatic way to print contents of `$0`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `sed` (which I don't recommend if `awk` or `perl` are available), then assuming that the sixth column is terminated by the line ending rather than a comma AND that fields do not themselves contain embedded (quoted) commas:

```
sed -E -e 's/([^,]*),/"\1",/1' -e 's/([^,]*),/"\1",/5' -e 's/([^,]*)$/"\1"/' file
"2018-03-18 4:56:17",255.255.255.255,00,ssh,"admin","123"
```

The general pattern is `s/([^,]*),/"\1",/n` where `n` refers to the nth occurrence of zero or more non-`,` characters followed by a `,` and `\1` is a reference to the captured pattern (between parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way for this: use the escape character \ when you put " before and end of the column.

```
cat test.txt | awk '{ print $1" ""\""$2"\""}'
```

give it a try.

Comment: Isn't that what [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437171/117549) demonstrates? It also seems like you'd need to print more fields to match the expected output.

Comment: In addition, the solution is wrong: on input `2018-03-18 4:56:17,255.255.255.255,00,ssh,admin,123`, it produces the output `2018-03-18 "4:56:17,255.255.255.255,00,ssh,admin,123"`. Please *test* before posting.